# I need to set all values in my dataset which are >1 to 1 in r

Tags: r, function

This may seem so simple, but im new to r and would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to set all outcomes in a variable/dataset which are above 1 to 1. putting the max value at 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know what your data is, but a simplest example:

```
> data <- 1:10
> data
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> data[data>1]=1
> data
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```